# UNC path not accessible after some time

Tags: networking, network-shares, windows-server-2008-r2, unc

I have a machine running about 100 processes each accessing a remote UNC path (to samba share) over and over to read files. From time to time the UNC (\server-ip\share) becomes non-accessible for this machine only. **Telnet** also stops to work. Ping to the inaccessible UNC ip DOES work. Only solution here is to restart this machine.

netstat -na does not reveal any serious problem e.g. too many hanging connections or hang waits.

Since path is fed to processes mapped drive cannot be easily used (anyway not sure if this can have an effect).

OS is Windows 2008 Enterprise R2 server.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Anything in a packet capture, E.g. Wireshark when it's failing? Maybe filter to "smb or smb2"?

Comment: Why are you killing processes? This is not usually a good idea as it prevents normal process exit cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

On Server 2008r2, network shares UNC or otherwise, are disconnected by default after a certain amount of time.

Using regedit

Go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\lanmanserver\parameters

find the autodisconnect value - If it's not there create a new REG_DWORD called autodisconnect

Edit/modify the value to Hexadecimal and type ffffffff then ok.

NOTE: The client-side session is automatically disconnected when the idling time lasts more than the duration that is set in KeepConn. Therefore, the session is disconnected according to the shorter set duration value between AutoDisConnect and KeepConn. To change the time-out duration in the client-side during a UNC connection, specify the arbitrary time in KeepConn.

Locate and then click the following key in the registry: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\lanmanworkstation\parametersValue: KeepConn
Data type : REG_DWORD
Range : 1 to 65535 (sec)
Default value: 600 sec = 10 mins

You can also use 'net config server /autodisconnect:65535' but I have had better results with the registry.

Comment: It seems this is to solve a mapped drive that after timeout displays the red X but when double clicked instantly reconnects. In my case (with no drive mapping) the specific unc won't reconnect even when typing the unc in a new explorer window.

Comment: Next thing I would try would be another network card - or a driver update for the card. Heard this kind of this happens with a lot of early realtek chipsets.

Comment: Also, what if you used IP instead of servername in the UNC string?